# Year Number/Month Short Text Columns to Dates MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've been trying to alter two columns (YR - Number Format & MTH - Short Text).  I've been trying to just use the below code.

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
ALTER COLUMN YR DATE;
```

But it just ends up deleting the entries. I have a column of Years - Number Format & Months - Short Text that I want them to say the same thing, but in a Date format so I can reference them.

I have...

```
2006 - Number

JAN - Short Text
```

I need them to be...

```
2006 - YYYY

JAN - MMM
```

so I can reference them.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider something like:

```
SELECT t.Years, t.Months, CDate([years] & "/" & [months] & "/1") AS ADate
FROM Table1 t
```

Answer (score 0):

Dates are stored a decimal numbers in Access, then formatted by the database engine to display in the local format.

You would have to store a date of say 2016-01-01 to store 2016 as a date you could reference as a "Date" in queries etc. Same with the month field.